# Copy-Paste text area in GIMP

Tags: copy-paste, gimp

I'm trying to copy-paste a text area into the same image to duplicate it. I don't really mind if it gets pasted into the same layer or another one.

I select the text area, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

A floating selection layer is created and if I move the text, it looks "empty" (the original text is black, the new one is white with slim grey edges, as if I was only moving a selection).

I read a bit about floating selections. I thought that clicking outside the selection would merge it into the existing layer. If I do that, the new (pasted) text area just disappears (as if I had just moved a selection). However, if I click "to new layer" in the layer panel, I do get a new layer with the text box in black characters as I expected.

What am I misunderstanding about floating selections and copy-paste?

Is there a better workflow to do a simple copy-paste, something that does not involve right-clicking in the layer panel?

Answer (score -1):

You can click the `Create a new layer and add it to the image` button at the layers toolbar to create a new layer for your texbox:

The icon to click on the toolbar

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).